# Branch circuit breaker ineffective at preventing mains trip

Tags: power, circuit-breaker

At my place of work, we occasionally deal with appliances which have faulty grounding resulting in an earth leakage trip. Some of these faulty devices have also been tripping the MCB, probably due to a short in the appliance. When the trip happens, the rest of my office trips. These are the 2 models of breakers that pop respectively:

CE463B, earth leakage: https://docs.rs-online.com/ddfc/0900766b8057a6bb.pdf

MT120A, MCB: https://hager.com/intl-en/products/information/mt120a-mcb-1p-6ka-b-20a-1m

I tried splicing a RCBO into a power extension to solve this issue, and I was hoping this would trip in its branch without tripping the mains. But now, both circuit breakers in the branch and mains trip together. Did I select the circuit breaker wrongly? If so, what do I need to look out for?
RCBO in power extension: https://docs.rs-online.com/2ee5/A700000008685742.pdf

Comment: Benjamin Tse - Hi, Practical questions about mains electrical installations are off-topic here and I migrated your question to Home Improvement.SE. But only then did I notice the detail that your question is about a **work** electrical installation. That makes it off-topic at Home Improvement.SE as well since that site only deals with *home* electrical installations. Sorry, that was my mistake. I have to wait for that site to close the question there. That doesn't change that fact that your question is not about [electronics design](/help/on-topic) or other subjects which are on-topic here.

Comment: Update: Home Improvement.SE will kindly take the question, despite it being in a workplace setting. Please use [this link](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/262634) and continue your question there. You will need to click "Join this site" on their site, to get an account there. Thanks.